# Is there a single word that describes someone who has delivered positive change to society?

Tags: single-word-requests

Think of someone like Tyra Banks who has pushed the envelope in the fashion industry and has created campaigns to increase diversity in beauty ideals and self acceptance.
Or someone who uses their career to benefit humanity and/or the environment in some way. Someone who has substance and has made a change and lives with purpose.

I was thinking an *influencer* or *revolutionary*, but it is too vague and doesn't nail it on the dot.

Comment: A *catalyst*? A *change agent*? *Trailblazer*? *Pioneer*?

Comment: *Humanitarian?* Which I'll admit to thesaurusing to by way of *benevolent*.

Answer (score 3):

A person such as Tyra Banks could be said to be a **champion**, **advocate**, **proponent**, or **promoter** of "diversity in beauty ideals and self acceptance".

From Dictionary.com:

> [**champion**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/champion?s=t): a person
>   who fights for or defends any person or cause
>
> [**advocate**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/advocate?s=t): a person
>   who speaks or writes in support or defense of a person, cause, etc.
>
> [**proponent**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/proponent?s=t): a person
>   who argues in favor of something; an advocate.
>
> [**promoter**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/promoter?s=t): a person or
>   thing that promotes, furthers, or encourages.

A person who uses their career to benefit humanity and/or the environment in some way could be said to be a **humanitarian** (as noted by @SteveSliva) or an **environmentalist**.

From Dictionary.com:

> [**humanitarian**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/humanitarian?s=t):
>   a person actively engaged in promoting human welfare and social
>   reforms, as a philanthropist
>
> [**environmentalist**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/environmentalist?s=t):
>   any person who advocates or works to protect the air, water, animals,
>   plants, and other natural resources from pollution or its effects

Answer (score 0):

Tyra Banks is  a *[net] **contributor** [to society/humanity/the environment ]*.

> **contributor**. 
>   A person who backs, supports or champions a cause, activity or institution.
>   *He was a regular contributor to Greenpeace protests.*
>   https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/contributor